# How to export a table to mysql server?

Tags: mysql

I have a table that I created in netezza and I want to export it to a mysql server. How would I do this?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you Googled? How did you arrive at the point of needing help?

Comment: googling `netezza export to mysql` will yield you tons of results that will help, don't make us do that for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this following command.

What did you use? are you using linux mysql server? or just xampp?

mysqldump -u  -p -h remote_server database_name table_name > text.sql

Comment: I guess I first have to use external tables to export it to a text file and then use the mysql commands to export the table to the server.